# How do i setup a button in cherrypy to not go to another webpage and just run method?

Tags: python, html, cherrypy

I am using cherrypy in python to develop a webpage. On this webpage I have a button to sound an alarm, when I click the button it takes me to blank page. Since I am not very familiar with HTML, is there a way to make the button just run the method and not go to the blank page?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As long as you do not render a new template. It won't go to a new page.
For example:
in HTML

```
<a href="alarm"><button>Alarm</button></a>
```

In Python:

```
def alarm:
   return sound
```